# Easiest way to check for include

Tags: sh

I would like to check for cpp files to contain

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

Since I do not want this thing to fail, when e.g. comments are in front of the include, I would prefer a way of checking, that honors the actual c++ syntax.
Can this be easily done (in a cross-platform way (using cygwin sh on Windows))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cpp`, the C preprocessor from the GNU compiler collection, has an `-M` flag that lists the files a C file depends on, i.e. the headers it includes. You could run `cpp` on all your files, then filter out stdafx.h. I don't personally use Cygwin, but I believe something like this should work:

```
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" -exec sh -c "echo {} && cpp -M {} | grep -c stdafx.h" \;
```

This `find`s every `f`ile with a `name` that ends with cpp, then `exec`utes a `sh`ell that in turn `echo`es the file name we're looking at. It then runs it through `cpp`, finally `grep`ping cpp's output for the header we're looking for and counting the lines. The output should look something like this (looking for stdio.h in the Git source tree):

```
./diff.c
0
./gettext.c
1
./gpg-interface.c
0
./hashmap.c
0
./hex.c
0
./environment.c
0
./remote-testsvn.c
0
./server-info.c
0
./compat/fopen.c
1
./compat/basename.c
1
./compat/strtoimax.c
1
./compat/hstrerror.c
1
./compat/pread.c
1
./compat/gmtime.c
1
./compat/setenv.c
1
```

Of course, if you only want to check a single file, you don't need the whole find invocation, you can just do "cpp -M myfile.cpp | grep -c stdafx.h" which will give you either a 0 if it's not in there or a 1 if it is.

Comment: Ah thanx, this looks perfectly. Sadly `cpp` is not installed on Windows, so we have to work around there.

Comment: `cpp` should be part of the `gcc` package thingy in Cygwin. You might have disabled it in the installer. Run the installer again and enable the Devel group.

Comment: The further problem is that when incoking cpp, you also need to pass all the include paths, so `cpp` does not emit an error.